# Vue frame work how to view my API items 5 in every row

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am using Vue for front-end and I want dynamic show 5 items every row 
some thing like that:

```
1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1
```

but when I loop on the array item it show every item in row.

Comment: Can you share the code you're working on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to use non blocking component like label in showing your item, then in the for loop use condition

v-if. Item index % 5 == 0  < br>
or create a div element when condition is meet